# How convert *uint64 and *uint32 data types to the int data type?

Tags: pointers, go, types, type-conversion

In my case, I have 2 variables with data types as `*uint64` and `*uint32`. I need to convert them to the `int` data type.

When I try to convert them with `int()` function, it raise such error:

> Cannot convert an expression of type *uint64 to type int.

I notice that the same `int()` function works without any problem if data types don't have `* (asterisk)` character.

So my question is how correctly convert `*uint64` and `*uint32` data types to the `int` data type?!

Comment: Note that there is no `int()` function. The expression of the form `T(x)` "where `T` is a type and `x` is an expression" is called an *explicit* [conversion](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't (shouldn't) convert a pointer to `int`, what you most likely want to do is convert the pointed value to `int`.

So simply dereference the pointer to get an `uint64` and `uint32` value, which you can convert:

```
var i *uint64 = new(uint64)
var j *uint32 = new(uint32)
*i = 1
*j = 2

var k, l int
k = int(*i)
l = int(*j)

fmt.Println(k, l)
```

This outputs (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/ExCYroZVx7j)):

```
1 2
```

Note that of course if the pointer is `nil`, attempting to dereference it (like `*i`) results in a runtime panic.

Also note that the the size (and thus the valid range) of `int` is platform dependent, it may be 64 and 32 bit. Thus converting any `uint64` value to `int` may lose the upper 32 bits, and certain positive input numbers may turn into negative ones.

Answer (score 0):

> [H]ow correctly convert *uint64 and *uint32 data types to the int data type?!

Like this

```
var a = int64(123)
var pa *uint64 = &a
var i = int(uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(&a)))
```

But note that while this is the "most correct way" to convert a *uint64 to int but that is almost certainly **not** what you want to do. What you should do: Learn the language and its type system and try to understand what pointer values are.

(Note the "most correct" as there *are* no correct ways to do what you asked.)